# What is this plant with bee-attracting small blue flowers?

Tags: identification

What is this plant with bee-attracting small blue flowers? Flowers are small, but they seem to be good for polinators.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: well it's not borage, that was my first guess..next..

Comment: what part of the world?

Comment: And how tall is this plant - its always good to add a picture of the whole plant so growth habit and foliage is clearly visible, as well as the close up pics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Cynoglossum amabile, although not being able to see an image of the whole plant means I'm only 99% sure. It's a hardy annual plant native to Asia, but used as an ornamental in some gardens. Common names include Chinese Hound's Tongue and Chinese forget-me-not, and it is in the same Family as Myosotis and Borage. It has hairy leaves, rather like Borage does, reaches around a foot to 18 inches tall and grows relatively easily from seed sown direct where it is to flower. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynoglossum_amabile

Comment: 99 percent sure?  Better than mine so I vote you up.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer Myosotis sylvatica, Forget Me Nots.

[Myosotis sylvatica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosotis_sylvatica)